# How can I copy a row from one table to another

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I copy a row from one table: 'tipuranibasti' (one column is of blob type for image) to  another table: 'puranibasti'.  With my code all fields copied to puranibasti  except a blob field[image field].

The blob field looks like [BLOB - 0B] in puranibasti table in database.

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");
$id=@addslashes($_GET['id']);
$image=@mysql_query("select * from tipuranibasti where id = $id");
$image_row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($image);

$name=@$image_row['name'];
$date=@$image_row['date']; 
$msg=@$image_row['msg'];
$image=addslashes(@file_get_contents($image_row['image']));


if(@mysql_query("insert into puranibasti values('','$name','$date','$msg','$image')"))
{
echo "image has been inserted successfully";
} else
{
echo "problem inserting the image";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What's the code you've tried? I'd say

```
UPDATE A INNER JOIN B ON A.some_id=B.some_id SET B.blobfield = A.blobfield
```

update: looking at your code, this is of course a different situation since you have the contents in a variable already. You might leave that out and do the UPDATE I proposed above afterwards. Alternatively, try without `addslashes`. Also, you might want to try using proper database variables instead of concatenating a string. Since the contents of the blob field are binary, I can imagine ugly things happen when you put them into a string.

Comment: thank you for reply...i have used another query that works::insert into puranibasti  select '', name, date, msg, image from tipuranibasti where id = $id